# Sparse Categorical Crossentropy Loss Seems Scaled Really High, Despite Very Successful Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm training some `CNN` networks on proprietary data using Tensorflow. We have boatloads of data, and it seems that these models are capable of learning a great deal of information about classifying data (all binary classifications so far).

Sometimes, the train/test accuracy curves can be remarkably good, upwards of 95% in some cases. However, the loss functions are suspicious in terms of scale. Visually, they look alright and about how I'd expect for something performing well, but it isn't the correct order of magnitude.

Can anyone tell me how this scaling is *usually* appropriately done in TF/Keras? I'm confident in these models, as they've been tested on other datasets and generalized very well, but the screwy loss function isn't very nice to report.

The learning rate is on the order of 0.0001. `L1` and `L2` are using the same lambda value, which I've had the most success with when providing to the model as somewhere between 0.01 and 0.03. I'm currently not using any dropout.

I'm including photos of a particularly highly variant accuracy run. This isn't always the case, but it does happen sometimes. I suspect that this problem is partly due to outlier data, or possibly the regularization values.

[image: train/test accuracy]

[image: train/test loss]

Here are relevant code snippets.

```
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

        if logistic_regression is not True:
            for i in range(depth):
                # 1
                model.add(Conv2D(
                    15,
                    kernel_size=(10, 3),
                    strides=1,
                    padding='same',
                    activation='relu',
                    data_format='channels_last',
                    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(
                        l1=regularizer_param,
                        l2=regularizer_param)
                    ))

                model.add(MaxPooling2D(
                    pool_size=(3, 3),
                    strides=1,
                    padding='valid',
                    data_format='channels_last'))

            model.add(BatchNormalization())

            if dropout is not None:
                model.add(Dropout(dropout))

        # flatten
        model.add(Flatten(data_format='channels_last'))

        model.add(Dense(
            len(self.groups),
            # use_bias=True if initial_bias is not None else False,
            # bias_initializer=initial_bias
            # if initial_bias is not None
            # else None,
            kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(
                l1=regularizer_param,
                l2=regularizer_param)
            ))
```

```
        model.compile(
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(
                learning_rate=learning_rate,
                initial_accumulator_value=0.1,
                epsilon=1e-07,
                name='Adagrad'),
            loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: The value of the cross entropy loss depend on the number of classes, how many classes do you have? Also the high value might indicate a problem in the confidences of the model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy these are binary classifications, i.e. 2 output nodes {0, 1}

Comment: What do you mean binary classifications (plural)?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy ah sorry that was poor choice of wording on my part. This model trains a binary classification. I only used plural because I have used this model on many different datasets, to form many binary classifiers. 

E.g., you hand the model patient #1, and ask, "of those 2 conditions, predict which one patient #1 has" for a myriad of different conditions.

Comment: This loss value does not look to be compatible or possible with a binary classification problem.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy could you please say more about why?

Comment: For binary classification, the maximum value of the cross-entropy loss is around 0.69.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy That is incorrect. You consider only the vanilla BCE loss, without regularization terms, for instance. A general Tikhonov regularization term could easily increase the scale of the loss. Losses are not meaningful in an absolute sense; only relatively. Look at the last layer. It has a regularizer.

Comment: @Rahul Ah yes - there's even regularization terms included in the convolutional layers as well. Is this normally accounted for when recording the loss function?

Comment: Yes, it is. Those regularization terms make it to the loss function, and you could pick which weights are regularized. If you have a weight matrix for a layer, and if you're using L1 regularization, then a `lambda * norm(W)` term is added to the loss.

Comment: @Rahul awesome contribution - thank you. Just so I'm completely on the same page: for both training and validation loss calculation, we add (lambda * w) for each w in normalized W to the loss value? Do you have any code examples you could point me to of this implementation in TF / Keras?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. [Here](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/#l2-class) is an example from the Keras docs. I can't find it in the TF/Keras code right now, but given an hour or so, it should be possible.

Answer (score -1):

You should not worry about the scale of your loss function values. Remember, the loss function is simply a measure of how far away your network is. However, you can always scale this any way you like. What does matter is the *trend* in the loss over epochs? You want it to be a smooth decrease, which is what your second figure shows.

Losses are just that: an arbitrary number that's only meaningful in a relative sense, for the same network, for the same dataset. It has no other meaning. In fact, losses do not correspond well with metrics either: see Huang et al., 2019.

> as they've been tested on other datasets and generalized very well,

That's what matters.

> but the screwy loss function isn't very nice to report.

You could scale these losses by 1,000. They're only meaningful in a relative sense.

**References:**

- [Huang et al., 2019. Addressing the Loss-Metric Mismatch with Adaptive Loss Alignment](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.05895.pdf)

Comment: Losses are not arbitrary numbers, they do provide useful information, so this answer is completely misguiding the question.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing this article!

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, They do not. They're only useful in a relative sense--with the same data and the same model. What does a loss value of 20.86 mean to you? Absolutely nothing. Meanwhile, an F-1 of 0.9 is pretty good, and you know the highest is 1.0.

Comment: That depends on the loss and metrics, there are losses that are interpretable by a human. There is no general pattern like you imply.

Comment: You're considering a very narrow space of losses. More generally, consider losses with Tikhonov regularization terms (L1 and L2 are special cases). Then, generally, you will have a loss at a nontrivial scale.